# any php encryption key?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minify / Obfuscate PHP Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064973/minify-obfuscate-php-code)

I have a php file. Anyone knows of any encryption technics/keys to encrypt the code? I don't want to make it human readable. I was thinking if i could include the encrypt keys in an include file hosted separately somewhere. Any help and ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to obfuscate the code. i've never do that on php, but i use yui for JS Code. I google'it and found http://www.codeeclipse.com/. Try that.

Comment: i think you can find more support for this on www.phpclasses.org/. May be not for free, but more economic than Zend Guard

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) ?

> Zend Guard, the most widely accepted PHP encoding and obfuscation product on the market, protects your application from unlicensed use and reverse engineering.

Comment: thanks man. any free tools out there??

Answer (score 0):

Nobody who cares a bit about security is going to use your app if it wants to include - e.g. EXECUTE - code from your server, loaded at runtime.

The only real solution if you really need to encrypt your code (usually you don't!) is buying ioncube or zend encoder to compile the PHP code to a bytecode which is then executed by a zend extension in the PHP core (i.e. the user needs to be able to load php extensions)